# Get 3 random, non duplicating objects from an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, promise

I am trying to randomly pull 3 objects from an array of objects. My array is coming from a Promise. below is the code.

Code:

```
var getLocations = admin.firestore().collection('locations')
                getLocations = getLocations.where('area', '==', game_area)
                let locations = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    getLocations.onSnapshot(snapshot => {
                        var results = []
                        snapshot.forEach(doc => {
                            let result = doc.data()
                            result.id = doc.id
                            results.push(result)
                        })
                        return resolve(results)
                    })
                })

                locations.then(() => {
                    // Shuffle locations array and get 3
                    const amountOfLocations = 3
                    const shuffled = locations.sort(() => 0.5 - Math.random())
                    // Get sub-array of first n elements after shuffled
                    let selectedLocations = shuffled.slice(0, amountOfLocations)
                }).catch(err => {
                    console.log(`ERROR IN QUERY: ${JSON.stringify(err)}`);
                })
```

Here is a sampling of the array returned from the Promise. NOTE: I simplified the results for this forum.

```
locations=[ { name: 'Radio Coffee and Beer',
    timestamp: 1580676902040,
    id: '1KALzdUbf7y3ex2C' },
  { name: 'ZACH Theater',
    timestamp: 1580676946375,
    id: 'Lpxl8xLKCFDKxIhc' },
  { name: 'Alamo Draft House',
    timestamp: 1580676636972,
    id: 'b5F3Tq2y9cD4WQJq' },
  { name: 'Stevie Ray Vaughn Statue',
    timestamp: 1580676764120,
    id: 'bIUl4JU7kUSh6eyi' },
  { timestamp: 1580676967508,
    name: 'The Long Center',
    id: 'xJJOprzYDt3fWqVa' } ]
```

As you can see this sample array has 5 objects. I would like to randomly pull 3 objects from the array. I think my issue comes from the way the Promise returns the array but I am not sure.

Comment: console.log(selectedLocations); what is the result of this?

Comment: @GangadharGandi it’s empty

Comment: @GangadharGandi it’s failing at shuffled

Comment: `locations` is a promise in this syntax: `locations.sort(...)`. You need to get the value from the promise and use that via `locations.then(values => {... const shuffled = values.sort(...); ... });`

Comment: @DanielWStrimpel I am a little confused. are you saying all I need to do is instead using locations.then(() => ... use locations.then(values => ... ?

Comment: Yeah, the `then` method is sent the value the promise resolves to.

Comment: @DanielWStrimpel you were correct. Thank you. Sorry but Gangadhar answered first, otherwise, had you given an answer I would have picked you. Thank you again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are directly working on locations which is a promise. When consuming promise using then, we will get the exact locations array.

Try like below,

```
locations
  .then((locs) => {
     // Shuffle locations array and get 3
     const amountOfLocations = 3
     const shuffled = locs.sort(() => 0.5 - Math.random())
     // Get sub-array of first n elements after shuffled
     let selectedLocations = shuffled.slice(0, amountOfLocations);
     console.log(selectedLocations); 
  })
  .catch(err => {
     console.log(`ERROR IN QUERY: ${JSON.stringify(err)}`);
  })
```

Comment: Note, though, the problem in the shuffling as described in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

As others point out, the fundamental problem is that the function supplied to `then` does not pass the location information through.  The code below fixes that.  But it also fixes another, more subtle problem:

*Your shuffling is not actually random!*

[An old article](https://www.robweir.com/blog/2010/02/microsoft-random-browser-ballot.html) by Rob Weir explains in detail why this is true, but here is a quick gloss on the idea:  Your shuffle uses a number of what are essentially coin flips inside the call to `sort`, 50-50 choices.  However many of those there are, the number of times it chooses one particular combination of results (say "Alamo Draft House", "Stevie Ray Vaughn Statue", "Radio Coffee and Beer") will show up some fraction of the time whose value must have a denominator which is a power of two.  It might show up 1/2 the time, or 3/8th, or 117/1024th of the times.  But it cannot show up 1/10th of the time or 1/60th.  Coin flips cannot give you that.  There are ten distinct combinations of three items (or 60 if order is important.)  So you cannot randomly shuffle a set of items with just coin flips.  This is a real-world problem as that article shows.

The most common way to shuffle is using the [Fisher-Yates algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle).  The code below modifies that to stop shuffling once `n` items are chosen (three for your case.)

So this code fixes the callback to the promises, and supplies a `shuffle` technique that fairly selects a subset.

```js
// Dummy implementation for demo
const locations = new Promise((res, rej) => setTimeout(
  () => res([ { name: 'Radio Coffee and Beer', timestamp: 1580676902040, id: '1KALzdUbf7y3ex2C' }, { name: 'ZACH Theater', timestamp: 1580676946375, id: 'Lpxl8xLKCFDKxIhc' }, { name: 'Alamo Draft House', timestamp: 1580676636972, id: 'b5F3Tq2y9cD4WQJq' }, { name: 'Stevie Ray Vaughn Statue', timestamp: 1580676764120, id: 'bIUl4JU7kUSh6eyi' }, { timestamp: 1580676967508, name: 'The Long Center', id: 'xJJOprzYDt3fWqVa' } ]),
  50 // 50 ms delay
))

const randoms = (count) => (xs) => {
  const arr = xs .slice (0), max = arr.length - 1
  for (let i = max; i > max - count; i--) {
    const j = Math .floor (Math .random() * (i + 1));
    [arr[i], arr[j]] = [arr[j], arr[i]];
  }
  return arr .slice (-count)
}          

locations 
  .then ((locs) => randoms (3) (locs))
  .then (console .log)
```